# Как сложить стопкой изображения при scrolling с уменьшением размеров

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть картинки природы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы эти изображения складывались друг на друга при прокрутке страницы с одновременным уменьшением размеров, как показано на этом изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока у меня есть только этот код:

```html
<ul>
  
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjoIv.jpg " /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4pB.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J6dK.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxnv5.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWP6Z.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpged.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBbpU.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h94b.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LycGT.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q556.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvKxT.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDYIU.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI0D0.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4qpY.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovzxV.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRI5i.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать, чтобы эти изображения складывались друг на друга при прокрутке страницы с одновременным уменьшением размеров, как показано на этом изображении:

Answer (score 4):

Ключом к решению является [**position: sticky;**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Элемент позиционируется в соответствии с нормальным потоком документа,
> а затем смещается относительно его ближайшего прокручивающего предка и
> содержащего блока (ближайший родительский уровень блока), включая
> элементы, связанные с таблицей, на основе значений top, right, bottom,
> и left. Смещение не влияет на положение любых других элементов. Это
> значение всегда создаёт новый контекст наложения. Обратите внимание,
> что липкий элемент «прилипает» к его ближайшему предшественнику,
> имеющему «механизм прокрутки» (созданный при overflow равном hidden,
> scroll, auto или overlay), даже если тот не является ближайшим
> фактически прокручивающим предком.

Такое поведение прокручиваемых элементов видно на примере ниже:
Второе изображение элемента списка будет подниматься до тех пор пока не прилипнет к верху первого элемента списка. ( `top: 0;`) Далее поднимается третий элемент списка пока не прилипнет ко второму элементу и т.д

Трансформация уменьшения :

```
li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.05) );
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.1));
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li {
  position: sticky;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: transparent;
  height: 100vh;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.05) );
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.1));
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.15));
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.2));
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.25));
}
li:nth-child(6) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.3));
}
li:nth-child(7) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.35));
}
li:nth-child(8) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.4));
}
li:nth-child(9) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.45));
}
li:nth-child(10) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.5));
}
li:nth-child(11) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.55));
}
li:nth-child(12) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.6));
}
li:nth-child(13) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.65));
}
li:nth-child(14) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.7));
}
li:nth-child(15) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.75));
}
li:nth-child(16) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.8));
}
li:nth-child(17) {
  transform: scale(calc(1 - 0.85));
}

img {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 200px 40px #fff; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  
  <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjoIv.jpg " /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4pB.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J6dK.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xxnv5.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWP6Z.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpged.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBbpU.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h94b.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LycGT.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q556.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvKxT.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDYIU.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI0D0.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4qpY.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovzxV.jpg" /></li>
  <li> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRI5i.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```